# Obter valor do input presente na row selecionada

Tags: php

Olá! Tentarei explicar o meu propósito da melhor forma possível.
Comecei a estudar PHP há pouco tempo, estou fazendo um sistema de cadastro e compra de produtos somente a título de aprendizado, porém estou enfrentando um pequeno problema.
Tenho os meus produtos cadastrados com suas devidas chaves numa *datatable*. Eu manipulo esses produtos, logicamente, através de uma conexão ao banco de dados. A seguir eu tenho a página **produtos.php** que tem como propósito exibir os produtos presentes no banco de dados e permitir ao usuário logado adicioná-los ao seu carrinho de compras. O problema é: eu não estou conseguindo obter a quantidade inserida no *input* para o produto solicitado. Segue o meu arquivo **produtos.php**:

```
$sql = "SELECT id_produto, nome_produto, preco_produto FROM produtos ORDER BY id_produto";
$stmt = $conexao->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

$num = $stmt->rowCount();

if($num>0)
{
        echo "<table>";
        echo "  <tr>";
        echo "      <th>NOME</th>";
        echo "      <th>PREÇO</th>";
        echo "      <th>QUANTIDADE</th>";
        echo "  </tr>";
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        extract($row);
        $preco_produto_reajustado = number_format($preco_produto, 2, ",", ".");
        echo "  <tr>";
        echo "      <td><div class='id-produto' style='display: none'>{$id_produto}</div>";
        echo "      <div class='nome-produto'>{$nome_produto}</div></td>";
        echo "      <td>R&#36;{$preco_produto_reajustado}</td>";
        echo "      <td>";
        echo "          <form class='adicionar'>";
        echo "          <input type='number' name='quantidade' value='1' min='1' max='20'/>";
        echo "          <button type='submit'>Adicionar</button>";
        echo "          </form>";
        echo "      </td>";
        echo "  </tr>";
    }
        echo "</table>";
}
else
{
    echo "Sem produtos.";
}
```

Como puderam verificar, o link de adicionar aponta para o arquivo **adicionar.php**. Nesse arquivo eu crio uma SESSION e armazeno as matrizes que eu obtive da row previamente selecionada no **produtos.php**. Dessa maneira, o produto em questão é guardado na SESSION junto com seus detalhes. Segue o meu arquivo **adicionar.php**:

```
<?php
    require_once("detectar-erros.php");
    session_start();

    $id_produto = isset($_GET['id_produto']) ? $_GET['id_produto'] : "";
    $nome_produto = isset($_GET['nome_produto']) ? $_GET['nome_produto'] : "";
    $quantidade = isset($_GET['quantidade']) ? $_GET['quantidade'] : "";

    if(!isset($_SESSION['carrinho']))
    {
        $_SESSION['carrinho'] = array();
    }

    if(array_key_exists($id_produto, $_SESSION['carrinho'])){

        header('Location: produtos.php?acao=existe&id_produto' . $id_produto . '&nome_produto=' . $nome_produto);
    }
    else    
    {
        $_SESSION['carrinho'][$id_produto]=$nome_produto;
        header('Location: produtos.php?acao=adicionado&id_produto' . $id_produto . '&nome_produto=' . $nome_produto);
    }
?>
```

Não estou sabendo como setar o valor do *input* para a variável `$quantidade`.
Como proceder? Agradeço desde já qualquer ajuda e peço perdão por quaisquer erros!

Comment: Acho que a melhor forma era usares um formulário com POST e esqueceres o GET. Ou senão tens de usar JS para alterar o valor.

Comment: @JorgeB.Eu andei tentando algo parecido, mas parece que o que me impossibilita de fazer isso é o loop do while, pois ele está criando vários inputs com o mesmo nome, e da maneira que eu coloquei aqui no código não está funcionando `<input type='number' name="quantidade[$row['id']]" value='1'/>`

Comment: não podes dar esse `name` porque podes ter várias quantidades iguais. Tens de dar um `name` que não se repita para que possas apanhar o `input` depois

Comment: @JorgeB. Após muito estudo fui capaz de resolver meu problema sozinho me utilizando de jQuery e matrizes para a SESSION. Obrigado de qualquer forma.

Comment: Faz uma resposta com isso.

Comment: @JorgeB. Feito.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Após pesquisar e estudar, consegui resolver meu problema utilizando jQuery e inserindo as matrizes dentro da SESSION. Postarei o código aqui para que futuramente possa ajudar quem passar pelo mesmo problema.
Na página **produtos.php**:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.adicionar').on('submit', function()
    {
        var id_produto = $(this).closest('tr').find('.id-produto').text();
        var nome_produto = $(this).closest('tr').find('.nome-produto').text();
        var quantidade = $(this).closest('tr').find('input').val();
        window.location.href = "adicionar.php?id_produto=" + id_produto + "&nome_produto=" + nome_produto + "&quantidade=" + quantidade;
        return false;
    });
});
```

No arquivo **adicionar.php**:

```
if (isset($_GET['id_produto']) && $_GET['id_produto'] != "")
{
    $id_produto = isset($_GET['id_produto']) ? $_GET['id_produto'] : "";
    $nome_produto = isset($_GET['nome_produto']) ? $_GET['nome_produto'] : "";
    $quantidade = isset($_GET['quantidade']) ? $_GET['quantidade'] : "";

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE id_produto LIKE '{$id_produto}' AND nome_produto LIKE '{$nome_produto}' LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $conexao->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();

    $num = $stmt->rowCount();

    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        extract($row);
        $colunas = array
        (
            'id_produto' => $id_produto,
            'nome_produto' => $nome_produto,
            'preco_produto' => $preco_produto,
            'quantidade' => $quantidade
        );
    }

    if(!isset($_SESSION['carrinho']))
    {
        $_SESSION['carrinho'] = array();
    }

    if(array_key_exists($id_produto, $_SESSION['carrinho']))
    {
        header('Location: produtos.php?acao=existe&id_produto=' . $id_produto . '&nome_produto=' . $nome_produto);
    }
    else if($quantidade <= 0 || $quantidade > 20)
    {
        header('Location: produtos.php?acao=quantidadeinvalida&id_produto=' . $id_produto . '&nome_produto=' . $nome_produto);
    }
    else if($num != 1)
    {
        redirecionar_para("produtos.php");
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['carrinho'][$id_produto] = $colunas;
        header('Location: produtos.php?acao=adicionado&id_produto=' . $id_produto . '&nome_produto=' . $nome_produto);
    }
}
```